# Put it into fridge

Tags: vocabulary

> Put it into fridge.
>   Put it into refrigerator.

Do we use *fridge* and *refrigerator*?

When we use *fridge* and *refrigerator*, are they the same?

Comment: They're the same. Over the last few decades, ***fridge*** has become increasingly common, and that is what I would suggest for informal contexts. Note that it's always *"Put it in **the** fridge"* (or *"the refrigerator"*). Using ***into*** there isn't actually wrong, but usually people would just use ***in***.

Comment: @Chipperyman I'm pretty sure that's exactly what FumbleFingers said...that you should use "the fridge/refrigerator" and that most people use only "in" instead of "into" but that "into" wasn't actually wrong.

Comment: @Doc Re-reading I understand that, I didn't realize he made the point that you have to use **the**.

Comment: If you say "into fridge", Derbyshiremen will think you're native, whilst everyone else will spot your foreign tongue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fridge" is is just short for "refrigerator".  It's considered a proper word now, not just an abbreviation.  However, it is still considered a short, informal form — for example, if you buy a fridge, the owner's manual will still say "refrigerator".

By the way, you are missing an article in those examples.  They should be:

> Put it into the fridge.
>
> Put it into the refrigerator.

Oddly, it is unusual to hear "Put it into *a* fridge" even when there is more than one refrigerator to choose from.  "The fridge" often just means any low-temperature environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *fridge* and *refrigerator* mean the same thing.  In British English *fridge* is so commonly used that *refrigerator* is very seldom heard and almost sounds old fashioned.  In my experience Americans seem to use *refrigerator* more often.

Comment: I've never heard **anyone** say refrigerator in an informal context.

Comment: Native Am.E. speaker, and I hear refrigerator used in informal contexts all the time.  Fridge is more common certainly, but someone saying "I just bought a new refrigerator" is more common than "I just bought a new fridge" (granted, people don't often buy the appliance).